# Change value of a property when selecting an item from select box in angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm new  to angular 2 .

I have the following code snippet.

```
<select name="shape_id" (change)="changeShape()">
    <option *ngFor="let shape of shapes" [ngValue]="shape.name">
      {{shape.name}}
    </option>
  </select>
```

In this while selecting an option i want to set the value of the selected   shape id to a property named shapeId in my component.

shapes is look loke

[{"name":"aa","id":"1"},{"name":"bb","id":"3"},{"name":"cc","id":"2"}]

can any one help me .

Comment: add ngModel to select tag ,declare shapeId in ts and in html [(ngModel)]="shapeId" and change [ngValue]="shape.id"

Answer (score 0):

```
<select name="shape_id" (change)="changeShape($event.target.value)"> // add this to change method
    <option *ngFor="let shape of shapes" [ngValue]="shape.id">
      {{shape.name}}
    </option>
  </select>
```

In **Component**

```
value : string;

changeShape(selectedValue : string){
    this.value = selectedValue;
}
```

**or you can go for either will work**

```
<select name="shape_id" [(ngModel)]="selectedVal"> // use ngModel here
    <option *ngFor="let shape of shapes" [ngValue]="shape.id">
      {{shape.name}}
    </option>
  </select>
```

this selectedVal will be a variable inside the Component

**Update After Comment**

```
<select name="shape_id" (change)="changeShape(i)"> // add this to change method
    <option *ngFor="let shape of shapes;let i = index" [ngValue]="shape.id">
      {{shape.name}}
    </option>
  </select>
```

pass the index value and then you can do a lookup in the component for the id and change `selectedvalue` to `selected index : number`

Comment: @Ajmalsha now that you have your selectedShape Name then you can find the in the shapes object array by using find property of array which will return you an object and you can use .id to get the id corresponding to the name

Comment: if i have 2 id with same  shape name then the result becom wrong.

Comment: Or beat is you can take the array index in ngFor right that will point to the particular array index and you can extract the values

Comment: if you don't mind .can you please provide me a sample code?

Answer (score 0):

This solution binds the selected object itself to a component propery, and you can process the selected shape in your event handler however you want.

Snippets:

Lets declare the structure first:

```
interface Shape {
  name: string;
  id: number;
}
```

Template code:

```
<select (change)="changeShape()" [(ngModel)]="selectedShape">
  <option *ngFor="let shape of shapes" [ngValue]="shape">
    {{shape.name}}
  </option>
</select>
<p>selected shape: {{shapeName}}</p>
```

Component code:

```
  private selectedShape: Shape;

  private shapes : Shape[] = [
    {name: "circle", id: 0},
    {name: "rectangle", id: 1}
  ];

  private shapeName: string;

  public changeShape() {
    this.shapeName = this.selectedShape.name;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

in your template -

```
<select name="shape_id" (change)="changeShape($event.target.value)">
  <option *ngFor="let shape of shapes" [value]="shape.id">
    {{shape.name}}
  </option>
</select>
```

in your component -

```
shapeId: string;

changeShape(id: string) {
    this.shapeId = id;
  }
```

Comment: <option *ngFor="let shape of shapes" [value]="shape.id"> notice the [value] property man

Comment: he is not looking for value